# Where to search for conferences and workshops in computer science?

Tags: journals, conference, computer-science, workshop

I'm a master student in computer science. I'm still working on my thesis and probably I will publish a paper, however I really have no idea where to look for workshops and conferences. I often hear my supervisor talking about some conferences and workshops and mentioning them, but I get no idea how he knew about them. Is there such a central website or search engine for this?

I'm new in research, never published a paper before.

Comment: (1) Ask your advisor.  (2) Look at where the papers you cite are published.

Comment: I found some decent ones here: [http://www.nsays.in](http://www.nsays.in)

Comment: One more that hasn't been mentioned yet: http://confsearch.org/ The nice thing about confsearch is that you can filter by sub-field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very good site for CS conferences and journals call for papers and their respective deadlines is [A Wiki Calls for Papers](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/).

Comment: similar website: http://eventseer.net/

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different websites and mailing lists for different subjects.  Some researchers also maintain webpages of conferences in their area.  I mostly learn about conferences through two mailing lists I subscribe to and two researchers' webpages, as well as emails forwarded by my mentor (I'm a postdoc).

Probably the best thing would be to ask your supervisor how he finds conferences.  He'll probably know the best sources for your research area.

One fairly general website I know about is www.conference-service.com, but in my area it's far from complete.

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about publishing, try one of these [conferences](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~zaiane/htmldocs/ConfRanking.html). These conferences are good, even at Rank 3. You also have the list divided by the area of interest.

Comment: One of the best comments too, but I can't accept 2

Comment: It's a great list, with the small caveat that it hasn't been updated in a couple of years which means that emerging fields and conferences may be under-represented.

Answer (score 2):

I may be biased (since I am working on that project) but I would start looking in the *dblp computer science bibliography*:

- http://dblp.dagstuhl.de
- http://dblp.uni-trier.de
- http://dblp.org

However, much more important than just searching for "any" conference and workshop in whatever repository is talking to your advisor, colleagues, etc and asking them for their opinion on which venues are most relevant for your specific topic.

Another way of finding relevant venues is just looking at the references in the literature you are working with. If there are some conferences or journals that come up over and over again, then they are probably interesting for you to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the conferences in Computer Science publish proceedings with Springer, IEEE or ACM (even though there are several dozens which self-publish or publish elsewhere).
All three publishers have lists of upcoming conferences:

**Springer**

- LNCS: http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-12-73665-0
- CCIS: http://www.springer.com/series/7899
- LNBIP: http://www.springer.com/series/7911

**IEEE**

- http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/index.html

**ACM**

- http://www.acm.org/calendar-of-events

Other great resources are mailing lists:

**Mailing lists**

- DBWorld https://research.cs.wisc.edu/dbworld/
- AISWorld http://www.aisnet.org/AIS_Lists/publiclists.aspx
- ACM SIG-IR list http://www.sigir.org/sigirlist/
- ECOOP info list http://web.satd.uma.es/mailman/listinfo/ecoop-info

Beware of conferences which do this just for money and not for disseminating knowledge:

- http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/

This being said - of course the best way is to ask colleagues working on a topic related to yours - like your supervisors, post-docs from your group etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found some decent ones here: http://www.allconferences.com/

I also receive a number of invitations through a number of mailing lists that I subscribe to.

You can also find a number of them through technology publishers like O'Reilly for example: http://strataconf.com/strata2014/public/content/home

Answer (score 0):

Another very useful site is [Conference Partner (myhuiban)](http://www.myhuiban.com). The site lists conferences by deadline, and shows useful information such as rankings by 3 different sources, years, views and so on. In each conference page, it also shows the call for papers, acceptance rate (when available), related conferences etc. Note that for some reason, full access requires (free) registration.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? To make it clear, I'm in no way affiliated with the site I mentioned, and other useful sites were already mentioned in other answers and comments.